# Story where humans fight aliens that were advanced in space travel technology but behind in warfare technology

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story where humans fight against aliens. The plot is, the aliens discovered gravitational space travel early in their history, and although being very advanced in space travel technology, the aliens are really late against human warfare technology.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. I hope you decide to stick around!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Road Not Taken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Not_Taken_%28short_story%29) by Harry Turtledove.

See also [Short story, where FTL travel is super simple](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33341/short-story-where-ftl-travel-is-super-simple)

Space travel is super simple, but somehow humans never discovered it. The aliens have never developed the alternative technologies we have, relying on conquest of primitive races with their space ships made of wood instead.

When they land on Earth, they get utterly defeated by our superior weapons and humans go on to rule the galaxy.

Comment: I searched for the story in this forum, but with only a part of the plot and English not my native language, I was unable to find the answer. Pardon for the disturbance.