# SF short-story about an alien invasion of Earth by backward aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, science-fiction-genre

The aliens have discovered a star drive for interstellar travel but are very backward in all other technology. The have conquered other races. When they reach Earth, the air on their ship is becoming increasingly foul. They land and find the Earth military just too advanced and aggressive to resist. They are defeated and their star drive technology falls into human hands, Read sometime in the past 3 years in a anthology of short-stories. Just can’t remember the title or author.

Comment: "The road not taken" by Turtledove (and if so, a target for multiple duplicates).

Comment: Royston, is it the same as [Short story, where FTL travel is very simple but humans never discovered it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33341/short-story-where-ftl-travel-is-very-simple-but-humans-never-discovered-it)? If so let use know and we'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, that's the one.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I have closed it as a duplicate.